# Google API: ServiceAccount errors with DirectoryService and DriveService using C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk, service-accounts

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

I have been working the past couple days to implement automation into my company's GoogleApps setup. I need to suspend users that have been inactive for 90+ days, deleting them a week after that. Before deletion, I need to backup any files found in their Google Drive.

**Why I haven't accomplished it:**

I have attempted this with a few different methods. First I was using the Admin SDK to interface with DirectoryServices, listing users, and suspending as necessary. This interfacing would also allow me to delete users when needed. Now, I need only backup their Google Drive files. For this, it's to my understanding that I need a Service Account to impersonate users, download their files, and relocate them (off to a server in bulk storage probably). I don't think this is possible as an Admin programatically because I believe UserCredentials requires user authorization for each user I intend to interface with via the Drive API, manually. On the other hand, a service account should allow me to impersonate users without authorization, provided the proper delegation.

I have created a ServiceAccount, provided it with Domain-Wide-Delegation, enabled the appropriate APIs (Admin SDK, Drive API) through the developer console, and provided the service account with appropriate scope through Google Admin Console security settings. I **think** that's all the setup I needed to do.

```
    private static async Task<bool> AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string keyFilePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(keyFilePath))  // make sure the file we're looking for actually exists
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not find ServAcct key file. Authentication failed!");
            return false;
        }

        string[] scopes = new string[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser, DriveService.Scope.Drive };

        // Generate certificate using our key file
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        try
        {
            // Create our credential from our certificate, using scopes
            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = scopes
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            // Create our services

            dirSvc = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "GoogleAppAutomation"
            });

            drvSvc = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "GoogleAppAutomation"
            });
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I am able to authenticate the service account in my code using the SA's email, and the P12 cert. Creation of the DirectoryService and DriveService objects using the ServiceAccountCredential works fine. However, when i go to access the services, I am presented with errors that I have failed to find any help for online.

**DirectoryService**

```
    // Acquire list of active users
    UsersResource.ListRequest req = dirSvc.Users.List();
    req.Customer = "my_customer";
    req.MaxResults = 500;   // 500 is max allowed. Must use paging (.pageToken) for more
    req.OrderBy = UsersResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.Email;

    IList<User> users;
    try
    {
        users = req.Execute().UsersValue;   // Execute request for user list
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("User List Exception", e);
    }
```

Sure enough, the catch block will throw an exception containing:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Domain not found. [404]
Errors [
    Message[Domain not found.] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
]
```

**DriveService**

```
        FilesResource.ListRequest lr = drvSvc.Files.List();

        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File> fl = lr.Execute().Items;

        foreach (Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file in fl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", file.Title);
        }
```

Just as above, the Execute() method throws an exception...

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup. [403]
Errors [
    Message[Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.] Location[ - ] Reason[dailyLimitExceededUnreg] Domain[usageLimits]
]
```

Looking in the Developer Console, this API has had no use at all in the Quota log.

So, I suppose my question is a very broad: what am I doing wrong? :(

## Edit:

I believe the issue pertaining to Google Drive access relates to a lack of Billing setup. I cannot be sure of this as of yet because my company is being very slow to get such a thing setup. If anyone can confirm or deny this for me, that'd help!

As for the Directory Service issue, I'll just use the Admin SDK to access the users for suspension/deletion, and the service account for Drive backup. I already have the Admin SDK working for this purpose, so no further assistance is needed in that regard (though an explanation of the error would be awesome since it doesn't appear to be documented whatsoever online!)

Comment: Just a clarification, [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) are server-to-server interactions between the web app and the google service. Its usually used when the application wants to use its own data rather than the user's - its not trying to impersonate the user.

Comment: I've updated the original post regarding my current situation.